# Bootstrap 5. list-group-numbered - I can't change to list-style-type: lower-roman

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, numbered-list

I'm trying to follow the documentation here:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/list-group/

"Numbers are generated by counter-reset on the , and then styled and placed with a ::before pseudo-element on the

with counter-increment and content."

```
<ol class="list-group list-group-numbered contract">
    <li class="list-group-item border-0 contract">
    copy
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item border-0 contract">
    more copy 
    </li>
</ol>
```

I've only just moved to BS 5.0, so that could be my confusion.

CSS works to change the font-size/color but not the style.

```
li.contract::before {
    font-size: 2.25rem !important;
    color: #AED6DE !important;
    list-style-type: lower-roman !important;
}
```

I can't find any examples of numbered Lists in BS 5.0, just the brief explanation in the BS docs.

Any examples/guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the property `content: counter(section, lower-roman) ". ";` to your `li.contract::before` class or to the `li.list-group-item::before` class like so:

```
li.list-group-item::before {
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    color: #AED6DE;
    content: counter(section, lower-roman) ". ";
}
```

Instead of using the `list-style-type:` property.

Explanation: This is because they mention in the [Bootstrap 5.0 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/list-group/) (you were on the right track but it is a bit obscure) in the Numbered Section, that "Numbers are generated by **counter-reset** on the `<ol>`, and then styled and placed with a `::before` pseudo-element on the `<li>` with counter-increment and content." So the counter needs to be styled/specified within the `<li>` css instead of specifying the `list-style-type:` property directly on `<ol>` or `<li>`. The [counter css](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-reset.asp) works by initializing it with a name and setting it to zero on the `<ol>` (parent element) using the `counter-reset: section` property, adding the counter to the `<li>` with the `content:` property, and then styling it with the same idea you were using to get the color and size to work (within/selecting the `<li>`, and in this case the counter name is section - which I found with an inspect).

[image]

Comment: Note: important! may or may not be necessary depending on where your css is. When I tested using page-level css it did not need it, but you may need it if you are using an external css page.

Comment: Thanks, yes no !important; was required. And you suggestion / explanation is very helpful. So glad I asked. I got stuck trying all sorts of options and not finding any examples. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome Nick :), interesting that the documentation also states that this was setup this way "for better placement inside list group items and to allow for better customization". While it may help with this, I feel like it would have been more clear if Bootstrap was able to leave the normal list-style-type...

Comment: Well, hopefully anyone who hits this problem can now find this post and your solution. The docs are a little sparse. Fine if you are an expert. This has got worse as Bootstrap has got more complex. Got to love StackOverflow.

Comment: Indeed! and ironically the whole point of Bootstrap is to make things easier so that one does not have to be an expert lol! Yes thank goodness for StackOverflow :)!